# Por qué el array es vacío?

Tags: javascript, array

No entiendo porque el array es vacío, hice lo mismo antes con otro carrito y salió bien, no sé cuál es el error acá.

```js
    let carrito2 = []

    const tiendadeconsolas = document.getElementById("tiendadecontroles")
    stockconsolas.forEach((producto) => {
    const div = document.createElement("div")
    div.innerHTML = `
    <div class="contenido">
    <div class="card border-info mb-3" style="width: 18rem;">
    <img src="${producto.img}" class="card-img-top" alt="">
    <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">${producto.nombre}</h5>
    <p class="card-text">${producto.desc}</p>
    </div>
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
    <li class="list-group-item">${producto.desc2}</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">${producto.desc3}</li>
    <li class="list-group-item"><strong>${producto.precio}$</strong></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="card-body">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" id="agregar${producto.id}">Agregar al carrito</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    `
    tiendadeconsolas.appendChild(div)

    const boton1 = document.getElementById(`agregar${producto.id}`)

    boton1.addEventListener("click", () => {
        agregaralcarrito1(producto.id)
      })
    })


const agregaralcarrito1 = (prodId) =>{
    const item2 = stockproductos.find((prod) => prod.id === prodId)
    carrito1.push(item2)
    console.log(carrito2)
}
```

[image: Acá se ve el array vacío]

Comment: Porque le estás agregando a `carrito1` y luego estás imprimiendo el contendido de `carrito2`?

Comment: Me sigue saliendo igual.

Comment: Debes poner un código reproducible

Comment: Como logro hacer eso?

Comment: En el editor hay un icono con este símbolo: `<>` debes poner ahí tu código, luego debes presionar "Ejecutar" y verificar que lo que has agregado reproduce tu problema. Si tu pones exactamente el mismo código que has agregado hasta ahora, no será posible porque al menos falta `stockproductos`,  etiquetas HTML como `tiendadecontroles`, botones ...etc